# What does "Devil's Keep" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I've heard this phrase used before, and it's the title of a book, a movie and a song. I've tried looking up the phrase but with no luck.

Does anybody know what it's supposed to mean/where it comes from?

Edit: I know what keep  means, I'm wondering if "Devil's Keep" has any specific meaning

Comment: A [*keep*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep) is a fortified tower within a medieval castle, so -- "devil's tower".

Comment: @Mick I know what keep means, it's just that I was wondering whether the phrase devil's keep had any specific meaning.

Comment: Not really. There may be a place called Devil's Keep, but if there is, Google doesn't seem to know about it (as you've probably already found out).

Comment: Prolly easier to read the book, watch the movie and or listen to the song, isn't it?

Answer (score -2):

I think it's a bay where there is Pirate Treasure kept in some old novel, not sure why I know that.  Search through Pirate story lore and you might find it.

Comment: Please explain your answer, preferably with some supporting statements and references. While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.